# Understanding a passage from Frontinus

Tags: latin-to-english-translation, terminology

I recently read the following complaint from Sex. Iulius Frontinus, who was made *curator aquarum* (supervisor of the aquaeducts) in 97 and later wrote a comprehensive work on the City's water supply (*De aquaeductu urbis Romae*, but also cited as *De aquis*), regarding water that was siphoned off the public network of pipes that ran below the pavement everywhere ([De aquis 2, 115](https://penelope.uchicago.edu/Thayer/E/Roman/Texts/Frontinus/De_Aquis/text*.html#2.114)):

> Etiam ille aquariorum tollendus est reditus, quem vocant puncta. Longa ac diversa sunt spatia, per quae fistulae tota meant urbe latentes sub silice. Has comperi **per eum qui appellabatur a punctis** passim convulneratas omnibus in transitu negotiationibus praebuisse peculiaribus fistulis aquam, quo efficiebatur ut exiguus modus ad usus publicos perveniret.

Here is my attempt at a translation, but the boldened part gives me trouble:

> Also we must end the profiteering by water officials that they call punctures. Hidden under the pavement, pipes run far and wide through the whole city. I discovered that these were breached (*through him that was called by punctures??*) in many places and, by way of private pipes, provided water to all businesses they passed by, and the effect was that too little water arrived at the public utilities.

I know not how to parse this, but here is how the Loeb edition (Charles E. Bennett, 1925) [translates it](https://penelope.uchicago.edu/Thayer/E/Roman/Texts/Frontinus/De_Aquis/text*.html#2.114):

> I discovered that these pipes were furnishing water by special branches to all those engaged in business in those localities through which the pipes ran, **being bored for that purpose here and there by the so‑called "puncturers"; …**

And [R. H. Rogers](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/R._H._Rodgers), the foremost authority on Frontinus of our (or perhaps any) time, translates the passage [thus](https://www.uvm.edu/%7Errodgers/Frontinus.html):

> I discovered that these were furnishing water in privately owned branch pipes to all the commercial establishments located along their path, **and that they had been tapped for that purpose here and there by the man known as "the puncturer."**

A footnote remarks: “Probably an informal title, but its form is akin to those used by official department-heads in the imperial service.”

Was a puncturer called *a punctis*? But why? What were those other department-heads called?

Comment: Is it possible that he's giving the derivation of the title without actually naming it, saying something like 'the one whose title comes from breaches (that the makes)'? I'm not sure why Frontinus would write in this oblique way – unless there were originally 2 words beginning with punct near each other, and one dropped out during transmission. Does the Latin text that you're using have an apparatus criticus?

Comment: “Ab + ablative plural” is a standard job title. The Secretary of State for correspondence is the *ab epistulis*, the person in charge of petitions is the *a litbellis*, and so on. So *a punctis* follows this pattern exactly.

Comment: @cnread PHI uses Kunderewicz's edition, which has what Sebastian has above.

Comment: @MartinKochanski. Interesting. I don't remember ever encountering such a thing, not even in Pliny the Younger. Do you know the grammar/logic behind this naming system? I assume some word or words have been ellipsed.

Comment: @MartinKochanski That comment would make a good answer.

Comment: @cnread The genitive would have hard times being substantivized. It is easier to use the phrasal equivalent "*ab/de* + N". So, the "*ab epistulis* (guy)" is the one "of the letters", it's just an empty *ab* whose function is merely relational. *appellare* is here constructed with a double object, "the one who was called a <name of the job>".

Comment: @VincentKrebs I fail to see how *ab epistulis* lends itself better to being substantivized than anything else. And *magister epistularum* is proper Latin; *magister ab epistulis*, unless I am mistaken, is not.

Comment: It's just the way they refer to some administrative functions. When the head N e.g. *magister* is present, yes, the genitive is used. But when it is implied, try saying *epistularum lectus est*, it's not intelligible; while *ab epistulis lectus est* means "he was elected letter-guy".

Comment: @VincentKrebs *Ab epistulis lectus est* means "he was elected **by** the letters," why that should be considered the more intellegible option is a mystery to me.

Comment: Have you ever seen a non-human *ab*-introduced agent? Just read *Ab epistulis <vir> lectus est.* To make it simple, *ab* with an object-referring N can never be interpreted as agentive. It denotes the origin, just like *de*. "the guy from the X department"